# Use an existing Elastic IP in CloudFormation template instead of generating a new one?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, yaml, aws-cloudformation

I currently have my template here which is to allocate an EIP for my instance. (Last part)

However, I would wish to use my fixed EIP instead of relying on CloudFormation randomly generating a new EIP everytime.

```
Resources:
  EC2Example:
    Type: "AWS::EC2::Instance"
    Metadata:
      AWS::CloudFormation::Init:
        services:
          sysvint:
            codedeploy-agent:
              enabled: 'true'
              ensureRunning: 'true'
    Properties:
      ImageId: !Ref ImageId
      InstanceType: !Ref InstanceType
      KeyName: !Ref SSHKeyName
      IamInstanceProfile: "EC2CodeDeploy"
      NetworkInterfaces: 
        - AssociatePublicIpAddress: "true"
          DeviceIndex: "0"
          GroupSet: 
            - Ref: "SecurityGroupIds"
          SubnetId: 
            Ref: "PrivateSubnet"
      BlockDeviceMappings:
        -
          DeviceName: /dev/sda1
          Ebs:
            VolumeType: io1
            Iops: !Ref IOPS
            DeleteOnTermination: false
            VolumeSize: !Ref VolumeSize
  ElasticIP:
    Type: AWS::EC2::EIP
    Properties:
      Domain: vpc
      InstanceId: !Ref EC2Example
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [AWS::EC2::EIPAssociation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-eip-association.html). In your case:

```
  AssociateControlPort:
    Type: AWS::EC2::EIPAssociation
    Properties:
      AllocationId: !GetAtt ElasticIP.AllocationId
      InstanceId: !Ref EC2Example
```